# ImageScraper does not work

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

Ok great.  So I've downloaded a module called imagescraper from

```
Pip install ImageScraper
```

When running in console

```
image-scraper 'insert url'
```

Works just fine. However following the documentation when I ran in jupyter notebook.

```
Import image_scraper

image_scraper.scrape_images('insert url')
```

I'm returned a *(0,  0)* tuple.

I've searched my working directory where my images suppose to be but it's not there.

My curiosity is no longer with scraping images. But I really just wanna work it out and figure why it's no working in my Python book.

Comment: Same problem on my side. The documentation of this library is so poor.

Comment: It is indeed. But the fact that it is working in console is killing me and not in py scripts is killing me. I have emailed the developers, hopeful of an answer.

Comment: You can report this as a bug on their GitHub account. If you're working on a serious project then do not hesitate to use alternative libraries (beautifulsoop,  scrapy ... and many others that are well documented)

Comment: Reported issue at, https://github.com/sananth12/ImageScraper/issues/92. Nah I know for a fact that there are 100 other ways to get it done in python. Somehow just want to figure this out if you get what I mean.

Comment: @user3288092: the way to figure these sorts of problems is to read the source code for the module. That's what I did... only to find that the function that you want to use is quite broken.

Comment: *Somehow just want to figure this out* This underlines you have a curious and scientific mind unlike many developers who just feel content to *make it run*.  You have +1 on the reported bug too :) Good luck curious man.

Comment: take in consideration the answer and comment of @mhawke

Comment: Thanks mate. =) hope my journey as a curious thinker pays off.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageScraper 2.0.7, the version currently available from PyPI, `image_scraper.scrape_images()` is bug ridden.

It fails to properly setup the `format_list`, which is a list of file name extensions for filtering image urls. Because it defaults to `[]` no urls will be selected for download.

In addition to that there are calls to non-existent functions, or more accurately, attempted calls to functions that are actually methods of class `ImageScraper`.

I'd avoid using it, or you could manually use the `ImageScraper` class. I see that you've already created an issue at the project author's github page, so you might want to await the outcome of that.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting information. and I agree for *I'd avoid using it,*

Answer (score 0):

This works, although it is not elegant - calls the non-Python command line version of image_scraper tool from inside Python:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
for link in your_list_of_links:
    subprocess.call(shlex.split('image-scraper ' + link))
```